# The request always failed/timeout at 30 second but in the postman the request need more than 30 second

Tags: http, https, axios, request, react-query

I have no idea what is wrong with my request, it's always failed in 30s, but I tried in Postman it's required more than 30s

```
axios
  .post(
    `${BASE_API_URL}/dataset/md.plan.season/data_read`,
    {
      params: {
        args: [
          {
            limit: 10,
            offset: 0,
          },
        ],
        kwargs: {},
      },
    },
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
      },
    },
  )
  .then((res) => {
    return res.data
  })
```

[image]

[image]

I've tried to set the `timeout` options in Axios but it's still doesn't work. Any idea? What makes Postman special? Or what's wrong in my request?

The response error it's just white blank and give `500` code

[image]

Comment: If it always fails at 30 seconds it is most likely a read timeout (no data received for 30 seconds -> abort request). But as your questions lacks details like the exact error message including error class type this is just a guess.